# Xcode 6.1.1, Yosemite, cannot add iOS device for testing

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

Since updating to Xcode 6.1, I cannot add any iOS devices to run on. Clicking add in the device window only asks to install more simulators. Itunes is 'seeing' the devices connected to the computer, but not Xcode.

Normally the devices I have on hand are an ipad2 running ios 7 and an older ipod touch running ios 5.1. I have set the build targets in the xcode project to include at least ios7.x but still can't see any device.

I have reviewed all my certificates and provisioning profiles in the developer portal. The ones generated by Xcode 6 seem to all start with "XC:..." If I generate and then download any of the older ones, they are greyed out in the add provisioning profile window from devices in Xcode.

Obviously, its critical that I can run on attached devices. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

thanks

r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Windows -> Devices (or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>). Click on the device in the left column, and then "Use for development." If you don't see it there, you may need to restart Xcode, the device, and/or your computer.

Comment: restarting both the device & the mac fixed this. Prior to that, I couldn't find a way to make any device show up in the devices window.